# How much do tunnels extend blast waves from explosives?

Tags: physics, hard-science, underground, explosions

Someone recommended this SE for this question, since I'm asking it to help a friend's setting, where dwarves and goblins fight underground with explosives. After asking if it was OK, I cross-posted this question from Physics SE: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/724102/how-much-do-tunnels-extend-blast-waves-from-explosives

To clarify something, though I've used the hard-science tag, I'd be happy with any estimate/formula more accurate than my own.

---

Someone taught me that explosive range is calculated with a simple inverse square law. If a blast is 10kpa at 1m in open air, then at 2m it should be 10kpa / 2m^2 = 2.5kpa? I've also heard it said it should be to ^3, but I think that's incorrect?

### This is how I was taught it works, with blasts in tunnels:

Regardless, in a tunnel the blast gets focused, and I wondered how large the danger area is by comparison. What I was taught, is you just take the volume of a sphere where the radius is the blast radius in open air, and convert that to the volume of the tunnel, to get the approximate range. It was also recommended to halve the result, to roughly account for inefficiencies like the tunnel walls absorbing the blast.

**Example:**
So if the blast radius is 20kpa at 10m in open air, and you blast it in a 4x4m straight tunnel of infinite length, the Volume of a 10m radius sphere is 4,188m^3, which would equal a 4x4x261.8m tunnel's volume. If you halved it, that'd suggest the blast pressure would be 20kpa 130.9m down the tunnel, and a lot more as you got closer.

**Thoughts:**
Not sure how accurate that estimate really is even as a rule of thumb, though. I know blasts are more powerful in enclosed spaces, but turning a 10m radius into a 130m radius is pretty extreme. Maybe that would be the case with really hard rock?

---

Either way, was hoping to ask to learn a bit more about blasting radius underground. A friend wanted my help on a story with dwarves having tunnel wars with goblins, and range of explosives is something I'm not able to give him a good estimate for.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. What hard science do you expect more on worldbuilding that you can't get on physics? Also considering that you haven't got any answer there, yet.

Comment: @L.Dutch Hello! Thank you! I'm not sure. It was recommended to me by an experienced user. He said some good physicists hang out here and would be interested due to the fantasy element. I'm hoping I'll get an answer in a few days.

Comment: This is something that mining engineers presumably need to worry about.  They are regularly blasting underground in tunnels.

Comment: You need to do some research into [air blasts](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/17480930.2017.1342064). In short, an air blast can be caused by explosives. It can also be caused by a sudden shift of rock by even a few feet. [Air blasts kill miners](https://www.resourcesregulator.nsw.gov.au/safety/safety-events-and-education-programs/learning-from-disasters/learning-from-disasters/1999). I'm not an expert, I just lived in an area with mines and you could hear the report of an air blast from miles away. Pull out your best Google and check it out.

Comment: consider a gunpowder charge in your open palm  does not generate enough force to damage your hand, the same charge confined by a gun barrel will propel a lump of lead with enough force to go through your torso. confining an explosive produces a drastic change. although you do need consider the volume of air the blast is pushing against, in a confined area the pressure wave is effectively compressing the gas ahead of it more and more so it reaches local equilibrium faster.

Comment: I think this is a really difficult question to tackle. Combustion and detonation are really complex problems that involve a mix of chemistry, kinetics, thermodynamics and (most annoyingly) turbulent fluid mechanics. You introduce some 3D constraints with low symmetry, and it sounds like you'd like ro go so far into the details as to consider the elastic response or fracture point of the rocks ("very hard rocks?"). I think an answer would require either experimental work or CFD simulations by an expert. Unless it has already been done, getting an answer is probably not gonna come for free.

Comment: @John Thank you all very much for the help and good points. Someone wrote a great answer on Physics SE, which I used to make a calculator, which I've shared below as an answer. Hopefully this adequately answers my question, to the rules. I tried to write it before, but I did it wrong, so it was deleted. Some people seemed interested in this question, but I'm not sure who, and I can't tag multiple people. Should I reply to the others?

Comment: this is not an answer, but you are correct that (neglecting dispersion), peak pressure of a blast in free space goes like the inverse square. This is because the energy is spread on the surface of an expanding sphere, and that area goes like the square of the radius. If confined to 2d (e.g. between ideal plates) peak pressure will be inversely proportional to the distance, and if confined to 1d (e.g. in a perfect tunnel) peak pressure will be constant

Comment: real tunnels will have energy transfer between the walls and the air, which I believe should result in a 1/r dropoff. Additionally, very close to the blast site (within a few tunnel-widths) you'll see 1/r^2 dropoff as the tunnel walls don't really factor in, meaning you'll see a brief 1/r^2 dropoff at the start, then a slow 1/r dropoff as energy leaches into the walls. The details of the rate of this dropoff will depend entirely on the materials (which is why this is given as a comment not an answer)

Comment: additionally you'll also likely see some pressure loss due to dispersion (causing the wavefront to spread out in the direction of travel). I don't have easy access to my notes on blast waves so can't calculate what the loss due to this will be, but iirc in areas where you still have a blast wave (rather than just a high-intensity sound wave) it should be fairly minimal, and so can be neglected here

Comment: @Tristan Thank you for the fine points, Tristan! I've actually written an answer which someone helped me with, which you might be interested in, that I believe take account of the factors you mention. Blast waves are apparently not so deadly as I feared.

Comment: There was a Mythbusters episode that looked into alleged German WWI trench construction techniques.  If memory serves, they found that right angle turns with sharp edges hinder propagation of explosions.  I'm not sure it would work fully enclosed, but it might be something to look at.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of this answer, I've made a calculator based off its formula, which I'm sharing here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yt9vuitqoh

According to it, to get 65psi, a certainly lethal amount, you'd need 2kg of TNT(?) from 2m away in a 4m^2 tunnel. I'm amazed it takes that much for such a short range. It takes a metric ton of TNT(?) to get 54psi@50m w/15m^2 tunnel. Ten million kg of TNT(?), in a 3,000m^2 tunnel will inflict 60psi at 1 kilometer, on the extreme end, and if you make the tunnel smaller than that, you get less effect.

It seems absurd humans can survive such proximity to such large explosives, but as far as I can see I accurately transcribed the formula. Notably, it doesn't include the material of the tunnel, so if it were something like clay instead of bedrock, you should get a lot less effect.

Additionally, if you used shaped charges so the blast couldn't travel backwards so easily, that would increase the force substantially. Possibly being the same as if you doubled Q, maybe? Not certain, though that's beyond this question.

Comment: to quote a comedian about hurricanes, "It's not THAT the wind is blowin', but WHAT the wind is blowin'." A human tossed about like a doll into walls with flying debris is dead very fast.

Comment: I agree, shrapnel and blunt impact (i.e. body hitting the wall) are the big killers here, not overpressure.  Also note that while it might need 65 psi to be "certainly lethal" people can and do die from much less, depending on their physical condition, direction of the blast wave, density of the medium (air vs. water), and probably other factors.